io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted
Follow is my JwtUtil code:
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

public class JwtUtil {
    public static String createJWT(String secretKey, long ttlMillis, Map<String, Object> claims) {
        SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;
        long expMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + ttlMillis;
        Date exp = new Date(expMillis);
        JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, secretKey.getBytes())
                .setExpiration(exp);

        return builder.compact();
    }

    public static Claims parseJWT(String secretKey, String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secretKey.getBytes())
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
        return claims;
    }

}


when i got Claims from frontend requestdata, i got
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:354)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541)`

String token = request.getHeader(jwtProperties.getUserTokenName());
Claims claims = JwtUtil.parseJWT(jwtProperties.getUserSecretKey(), token);

io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:354)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541)


what is your mechanism for secret key ? is it fix or change ?
